# Is void f() = 0 a virtual method?

Tags: c++, methods, virtual, abstract-class, derived-class

Kind of a noob doubt here (another one from me :P )

Regarding a book I'm reading:

- One Abstract Base-Class(**ABC**) is so by the declaration of a pure virtual method.
- What makes a method a pure virtual method is the `= 0` at the end of the declaration.
- You can declare one as this: `virtual void f() = 0;` This way you don't need to define it in the ABC, but it's mandatory for the derived classes to implement its own versions of it.
- But you can also declare a virtual method like this: `void f() = 0;` This way you'd need to define the method in the ABC, and the derived classes could use it like that. This approach is needed for ABCs whose methods are all commonly applied by its derived classes.

**If all the points above are true**, what I don't understand is: What is exactly a virtual method?

Because `void f() = 0;` looks like a regular method to me. The ABC would define it, and the derived objects would use the ABC's definition, just like any other public method. Is there a definition of virtual method that is compelling for these two instances?

> A pure virtual function or pure virtual method is a virtual function
>   that is required to be implemented by a derived class that is not
>   abstract

This definition is picked from another question from this site. So my guess is the book I'm reading is wrong? `void f() = 0;` states the class is an ABC but it's not a pure virtual method. Could somebody confirm this or explain it to me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
void f() = 0;
```

Is wrong unless a base class defines `f()` as `virtual`. For example:

```
class A
{
public:
   virtual void f() = 0;
};

class B : A
{
   void f() = 0;
}
```

The above is legal because `f()` is inherently `virtual`. Otherwise, no.

**tl;dr** you can't declare a non-virtual method as pure, but a method can be virtual without explicitly specifying the `virtual` keyword (via inheritance). I hope this is what the book is talking about, otherwise I'm inclined to say it's a <del>crappy</del> bad book.

Comment: Would `B::f` be whatever `A::f` is once we define the body of `A::f() {...}`??

Comment: @David no, not if you override it in `B`.

Comment: Does the `void f() = 0` in `B` imply that derived classes of `B` must implement their own version of `f`?

Comment: @David not necessarily. The derived classes can also declare `f` as pure, but they'll be abstract too.

Comment: So how exactly does `f` get defined?

Comment: @Luchian Grigore so, what's the workaround for an abstract base-class whose methods are all commonly used by it's derived classes? I'll put some code in the question if you want me to be more specific.

Comment: @David if you mark it virtual pure, you don't have to define it.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore So what use is `f` then?

Comment: @Kurospidey usually, a workaround assumes there's a problem. I don't see a problem. Perhaps ask a new question (editing this question will change it completely, better to post a new one with what you're trying to achieve)

Comment: @David it's the OOP concept of abstraction. Somewhere along the hierarchy you can define it, but use pointers or references to the base class. When you call it, you don't need to know the exact type. For example, a base class `Animal` has the method `eat` virtual pure. A derived class `Dog` implements that method. You can have a pointer to an `Animal` which points to a `Dog` (but you don't know that) and call `eat`, without having to worry about the actual implementation.

Comment: @Luchian Grigore ok, thanks for that. But imagine there's an abstract class whose methods can be implemented all by itself. The derived classes don't have special implementations for the common methods, they only add new ones to the core abstract class. So they have in common all the methods and are implemented the same, but they add new, different ones. Though thinking of it, I could abstract some different methods as a common one in the ABC.

Comment: @Kurospidey then perhaps those methods shouldn't be virtual.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore yep, but I mean, I'd need to make at least one pure virtual to make the base-class abstract. But I think I understand it now, and the "workaround" would be easy. i.e. baseclass: shape, derived classes: circle, rectangle. I could declare a pure virtual method called area(). It's common for both but it's implemented differently. The key is finding this pure virtual method to declare in the ABC. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Kurospidey oh, I see. That's usually achieved by marking the destructor pure virtual.

Answer (score 1):

A **function** (C++ doesn't have methods) is virtual if it is marked `virtual` or if it overrides a virtual function in a base class. A virtual function can be marked "pure virtual" with `= 0`; this means that the function doesn't have to be defined, and classes derived directly from the class are also abstract classes unless they override that function (and any other pure virtuals). An overriding function can also use `= 0` to make the overrider pure virtual.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore - you don't think **what** is true? Surely there's something in what I said that is correct... `<g>`

Comment: "Method" is a computer science term for a member function (or a function associated with an object). In that way C++ does have methods. Using the same naming convention for things is highly important and in thus in this regards I consider your statement <quote>C++ doesn't have methods</quote> not only wrong but rather misinformation.

Comment: @LokiAstari - read the C++ standard: it doesn't use "method" in that sense anywhere. Using the same naming convention is highly important; the C++ standard should be a guide to terminology.

Comment: @LokiAstari - "irrelevant"? I think this discussion is over. Thank you for your input.

Comment: @Peter Becker: I know the C++ standard does not mention it. But as I pointed out in my last post that is irrelevant. The meaning of the term "Method" is well defined. And you can not write English without context the context here is computer science (you can consider it the meta language on which meanings are based).